# Google Sheet arrayformula referencing previous row of same column: error circular reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to create array formula that references the previous row.
Keep getting #REF error:

```
Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Spreadsheet Settings.
```

Saw many other posts with a similar question, but none of them seemed to solve it for me.

User enters details in column A and column B should show start/busy/end. E.g.

```
|A              | B            |
|---------------|------------- |
|[heading A]    | [heading B]  |
|start          | start        |
|something      | busy         |
|something else | busy         |
|end            | end          |
|something      |              |
|something else |              |
|start          | start        |
|something      | busy         |
|end            | end          |
|start          | start        |
|end            | end          |
|...            | ...          |
```

Tried in B2 and got the circular reference error:

```
=arrayformula(if((A2:A="start")+(A2:A="end"),A2:A, if((A1:A="start")+(B1:B="busy"),"busy","") ))

=arrayformula(if((A2:A="start")+(A2:A="end"),A2:A, if((A1:A="start")+(offset(B2:B,-1,0)="busy"),"busy","") ))
```

This one shows `busy` at the first row after a start lines (because of the `A1:A="start"` test), but not for the other "busy" rows (so: the `indirect("B"&row(B2:B)-1)="busy"` test is not working).

```
=arrayformula(if((A2:A="start")+(A2:A="end"),A2:A, if((A1:A="start")+(indirect("B"&row(B2:B)-1)="busy"),"busy","") ))
```

For that one, when I replace the `""` with `"B"&row(B2:B)-1`, then it displays the indirect cell reference as I would expect, e.g. in `B4` it shows "B3".

Suggestions how to fill the start/busy/end values using arrayformula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in cell `B1`:

`=arrayformula({"[Heading B]";if(A2:A="start","start",if(A2:A="end","end",if(COUNTIFS(A2:A,"start",ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A))=COUNTIFS(A2:A,"end",ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A)),,"busy")))})`

[image]

Notes:

I check for the following conditions:

A) sequence of the word 'start'

`=arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"",COUNTIFS(A2:A,"start",ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A)),))`

B) sequence of the word 'end':

`=arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"",COUNTIFS(A2:A,"end",ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A)),))`

C) whether A) and B) are the same for each row. Where they are the same, the item is either an 'end' closing a 'start', or 'something else' that we need to ignore.

`COUNTIFS(A2:A,"start",ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A))` = `COUNTIFS(A2:A,"end",ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A))`

D) The final logic identifies 'something else' after an 'end' and ingores it:

`=arrayformula(if(A2:A="start","start",if(A2:A="end","end",if(xxx,,"busy"))))` where xxx is whether item C) above is true.

[image]

Comment: yes that works! Quite a different route than I was expecting. Looking forward to the notes. Is it easy to explain why the more obvious route is failing?

Comment: Your initial formula in col B is referencing col B, so that will cause the circular issue.

Comment: well done! So the key part seems to be the `countifs` limiting the range to look at. Still not sure what exactly was causing the circular reference.

Comment: Yes, where the running row count of 'start' equals the running count of 'end', it is either an 'end' closing a 'start' or it's the 'something' else condition that you want to ignore. :-)